# Want to get the length condition of innerText for the number of instances not the number of characters

Tags: javascript

I have: document.querySelectorAll('div.stops') that appears with innerText "Direct" twice on the page.

So I want to apply a condition that if the text "Direct" appears twice, then do something. I have a code like below, but it does not give me the length of the number of times the word "Direct" appears. Instead, it just gives me the number of characters, which is 6.

```
for(let i=0; i < document.querySelectorAll('div.stops').length; i++){
if (document.querySelectorAll('div.stops')[i].innerText == 'Direct'){
// Do something
}}
```

Image where the text "Direct" appears 2 times

[image: Image where the text "Direct" appears 2 times]

Screenshot of the console where I tried to find the length

[image: Screenshot of the console where I tried to find the length]

Comment: your code is good, but why in console, you are trying to access `document.querySelectorAll('div.stops').innerText`, as you know it's an array of nodes and not have innerText, you should use `document.querySelectorAll('div.stops')[0].innerText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cache your elements. Use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create an array from [the "array-like" list of nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) that `querySelectorAll` returns. That way you have access to array methods like `filter`.
2. [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the elements that have 'Direct' as their textContent. Note: `filter` returns a new array.
3. If the length of that array is 2 do the thing.

```js
const stops = document.querySelectorAll('.stops');

const direct = Array.from(stops).filter(stop => {
  return stop.textContent === 'Direct';
});

if (direct.length === 2) {
  console.log('Good');
}
```

```html
<div class="stops">Direct</div>
<div class="stops">Karen</div>
<div class="stops">Indirect</div>
<div class="stops">Bus</div>
<div class="stops">Banana</div>
<div class="stops">Direct</div>
```